# Smallest NFA accepting concatenations of two words of the length $k$ which are different at all positions

Tags: formal-languages, finite-automata, nondeterminism

Let $k\in \mathbb N$

I'm looking for a small NFA build for the language of concatenation of two words of the length $k$ which are index-wise different, i.e. $$L_k=\{u\cdot v \in \Sigma^* : |u|=|v|=k\wedge \forall i, u_i\neq v_i\}$$

Notice that since $k$ is fixed, $|L_k|=(|\Sigma|\cdot(|\Sigma|-1))^k$, and is regular as a finite language.

$%$

The trivial DFA for the language contains $k$$|\Sigma| \choose k$$+1$ states and just "remembers" which letters it have seen during the first $k$ letters, however if $k=o(|\Sigma|)$, we can create a significantly smaller NFA.

$%$

A "simple" NFA for it would be of size $O^*(2^{2k})$ (more precisely, $O(k^2 \log |\Sigma| 2^{2k+O(\log^2 k)})$ ):

$%$

1. Take a $(|\Sigma|,2k)$-universal set (i.e. a set of vectors $\mathcal V\subseteq \{0,1\}^{|\Sigma|}$ such that for every vector $u\in \{0,1\}^2k$ and a $2k$ indices, there exists a vector $v\in \mathcal V$ such that $v_{|I}=u$, i.e. if we look only at these $k$ indices in $v$ we find $u$). Such families of size $O^*(2^{2k})$ are known.

   We think of each vector $v$ as a function $\Sigma\to \{0,1\}$, where $v(\sigma_i)=1⟺v_i=1$.

$%$

1. Create an NFA as follows:

   1. From the starting state $q_0$ create an $\epsilon$-transition to a new state for any $v\in \mathcal V$. Denote this state by $q_v$.
   2. From each $q_v$ build a path of states which accepts all words whose first $k$ letters are mapped by $v$ to 0, and the later $k$ letters are mapped by $v$ to 1.

$%$

Basically, the idea is that the universal set allowes us to partition the letters which are allowed to appear in the first $k$ symbols from the rest, and we get every word in the language since there has to be a corresponding vector $v\in \mathcal V$ which partitions it right.

So the questions are:

> **What is the size of the smallest NFA for $L$?**
>
> **Is this construction optimal?**
>
> **What lower bound we can prove for such automaton size?**

Comment: somewhat related [computing minimal NFAs from DFAs](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/10829/computing-the-minimal-nfa-for-a-dfa) tcs.se

Comment: Thanks @vzn. Indeed, had $DFA\to NFA$ minimization been poly-time solvable, this question becomes useless. Unfortunately, as it's PSPACE-complete, we have to work hard to build small NFAs for interesting languages.

Comment: why do you say it is "useless" if it is in PTime? to me that would only mean there is an efficient algorithm for it. anyway this seems rather abstract/ theoretical (verging on research/ [cstheory.se]), does it have more bkg/ motivation/ application?

Comment: @vzn - this language is a special case of a language I use for developing parameterized algorithms for a family of packing problems. It uses an automaton for the language, in addition to constraint from the input and checks if it's language is empty.
I can't expand too much on the usage (as it's still a work in progress), but the letter difference basically ensures that every items isn't packed "too many times". I've simplified the language as much as possible, but I believe that any technique used to build NFA for $L$ would help me improve my construction for the actual language I'm using.

Answer (score 4):

Update: this doesn't answer the question that the original poster was looking for, and doesn't help with  the general case where $|\Sigma|>2$, so the question remains open.

---

Here is a simpler construction, showing that in the case where $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$, $O(k \cdot 2^{2k})$ states suffice, and in fact you can recognize the language with a *DFA* with that many states.

Let's start by looking at the complement language:

$$\overline{L_k} = \{u \cdot v \in \Sigma^* : |u| = |v| = k, \exists i . u_i = v_i\}.$$

Notice that this can be recognized by a NFA with $2k^2 |\Sigma|$ states.  The NFA first guesses $i$ and a symbol $x$, then accepts all strings $u \cdot v$ where $u_i = v_i = x$.

Convert this to a DFA using the standard subset construction.  We get a DFA with $\le 2^{|\Sigma| k + 1} k$ states.  Now we can compute its complement, which is another DFA with the same number of states that recognizes $L_k$.  Since it is a DFA, it is in turn automatically a NFA, too.

This beats your construction for the case where $|\Sigma|=2$, but otherwise leads a NFA that's larger than your scheme.  However, I thought it might be of interest, both because it is so simple, and because it in fact provides a DFA (not just a NFA) to recognize your language $L_k$.

Comment: Thanks @D.W. for the answer. It is a nice construction, but in my application $k<<|\Sigma|$.

Comment: @RB, OK, no problem!  Your construction is nicer.  You might want to edit your question to mention that in your application $k \ll |\Sigma|$.